# SpringBoot and @CrossOrigin annotation with POST only

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, cors

I have the following class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bets")
@CrossOrigin
public class BetRestController {

    @Autowired
    private BetController betController;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public BetResource betOnGame(@RequestBody @Valid BetResource betResource) {
        return BetTranslator.from(betController.betOnGame(BetTranslator.from(betResource)));
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<BetResource> getAllBets() {
        return betController.getAllBets().stream().map(BetTranslator::from).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to access the POST method I am getting:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/bets. Origin http://localhost:3000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

but GET method works.

What I have wrong in my configuration or maybe there is a bug in @CrossOrigin annotation processing?!

Comment: can you post the HTTP request and Response headers(from the Network)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it is possible to specify CORS origin on one specific method.

**Sprint Boot documentation** : https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

> **Enabling CORS**
>
> ***Controller method CORS configuration***
>
> So that the RESTful web service will include CORS access control
>   headers in its response, you just have to add a @CrossOrigin
>   annotation to the handler method:

Here's the example from Spring boot website :

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9000")
@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public @ResponseBody Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(required=false, defaultValue="World") String name) {
    System.out.println("==== in greeting ====");
    return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template, name));
 }
```

Comment: If you look at my example this is exactly what I did. Though I am getting cross origin problem for my post method and for get not.

Comment: Can you please provide HTTP headers of both POST and GET requests ?

Comment: the problem was in client code because on this context i have two methods get and post with following the code works as expected: 
  private makePostRequest(path:string, body: any) {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let url = `http://betty-backend.cfapps.io/${ path }`;

    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), { headers: headers })
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  } and the annotation @CrossOrigin
 is necessary